# onclick event popup in mapkit xcode 8

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

i have a project done with maps using Open Street Map in xcode mapkit i already added there map and created a polyline, polygon, markers with popups. 
**i have remaining two parts to do** one is to add zoom buttons to map

- second one is i need to add a onclick event when i touch somewhere in the map place on the map i need to show a
  popup event showing "hey u touch this lat,long".

i used several ways doing researches but i could not archive my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `MKMapView` in your `viewDidLoad` method

**like this**

```
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.showPopup(tapGesture:)))
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

after that you need to implement the Tap selector method, the main issue you will found is get the real location based on the touch screen coordinates your can do that using the `MKMapView` `convert` method

**like this**

```
let coordinate = self.mapView.convert(tapGesture.location(in: self.mapView), toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView) //here we convert touch location from Screen location to map coordinates
```

**Your full code for show an alert popup with coordinates touched**

```
func showPopup(tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let coordinate = self.mapView.convert(tapGesture.location(in: self.mapView), toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)
    let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: "TOUCH IN MAP", message: "coordinate is lat: \(coordinate.latitude) long: \(coordinate.longitude)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    alertViewController.addAction(action)
    self.present(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: @Saneth let me know if my answer helps you

Comment: I got an error in convert method  saying " Use of unresolved identifier 'tap Gesture' " so I changed tapGesture to tapGestureRecognizer then the code looks like                                                                                             "_ = self.mapView.convert(tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.mapView), toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView) "
then it started working

Comment: its wierd @Saneth this code was tested, but anyway Iam glad to help you, best regards

Comment: thnk u :) however it works